# User Needs To Wait For Operation To Finish

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have an app where a user imports data to my server. So, when the user clicks Import button, select CSV file - the app will start to save the data to my database. This can be done easily on Backgroundworker - been using this a lot on my app.

But, the problem is my user needs to wait for the operation to finish before importing another CSV file to database. Since, I think, background worker can only do one operation at a time, are there any way to resolve this?

Comment: If you're targeting a recent version of the framework, you can use `Async` and `Await` (i.e. the TAP pattern).  With [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap), this kind of thing can be done in a much more readable fashion.

Comment: You could use a progress bar in order to give to the user the feedback that an operation is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't want your user to wait, so a much simplified answer would be like this. `Task.Run` creates a new thread each time it is executed, so in it's simplest form you can do this - with the usual caveats about updating the UI of course.

```
Private Sub SaveCSV()
    Task.Run(Sub()
                 'code to save csv
             End Sub)

End Sub

Private Sub LoadCSV()
    Task.Run(Sub()
                 'code to load csv
             End Sub)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have three Functions that I use:

1. ) I am using MongoDB as my app's database and, to import CSV data, I used `mongoimport`. Since `mongoimport` can only be run by the system command line, I am using `Process` to open up the `cmd prompt` and input the line there. 

2. ) On the command prompt, I want to get the output for the progression of `mongoimport`. Thus, I am checking its `DataReceivedEventArgs`.

3. ) For every error and/or output of `DataReceivedEventArgs`, I am appending it on my main UI.

So, I got three Functions. Can I add these on one Task.Run?

Comment: My apologies for not adding that information on my post.

Comment: Yes you should be able to, but having them in separate tasks means that each will run on its own thread, and it will take less time to complete them both.